# how to use the Google Tag Manager plugin for gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, gatsby

Please note that I'm still learning to use Gatsby & React.

I have been trying to figure out how to properly use the Google Tag Manager Plugin for Gatsbyjs to insert tracking codes into my app.

The [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager) of the plugin does not provide a lot of insights and examples, so I'm not sure if I understand it completely.

What I want to do is to insert two GTM tracking codes into my app, one in `<head>` and one in `<body>`. With the static site approach, I could just copy and paste the GTM tracking codes into my HTML documents, however, with Gatsby & React, it does not work that way.

For example, I want to insert the following code to the `<head>`

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

I open the gatsby-config.js file and paste the following under plugins

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager`,
    options: {
      id: "YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ID",

      // Include GTM in development.
      // Defaults to false meaning GTM will only be loaded in production.
      includeInDevelopment: false,

      // Specify optional GTM environment details.
      gtmAuth: "YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ENVIROMENT_AUTH_STRING",
      gtmPreview: "YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ENVIROMENT_PREVIEW_NAME",
    },
  },
]
```

It seems like the only thing I need to do here is replacing 'YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ID' with my own GTM-ID.
However, after I've done that and check the source code after the build, it shows

```
<script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXX;gtm_auth=YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ENVIROMENT_AUTH_STRING&amp;gtm_preview=YOUR_GOOGLE_TAGMANAGER_ENVIROMENT_PREVIEW_NAME&amp;gtm_cookies_win=x"></script>
```

am I missing something here, Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to be using the plugin mentioned in your question then you can just insert that plugin in `gatsby-config.js` file inside [plugin property](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-two/#gatsby-plugins).

However, if you just want to plop the `<script>` tag that GTM provides you then you'd have to customize the [`html.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/) file of gatsby a little. Basically, it will let you put anything you'd like just like in any of your other html files.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My question is how to properly configure the plugin so that I can achieve the result that I want. I followed the official example and replaced GTM ID, but the problem is that the generated script is not matching with the google generated script.

Comment: Okay, I just tested it in my machine. If you're not using `optional GTM environmental details` then go ahead and remove them. Also, don't forget to check your adblocker settings. Stricter adblockers will block GTM. And lastly, if it doesn't show up on `gatsby develop` then try with `gatsby build`.

Comment: On this, I would love to know if anyone knows what's the difference between using the plugin v/s directly inserting the same through the html.js?

Comment: My problem is similar to him, I am using the gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager plugin but now I wanted to add one more GTM tag based on certain route condition, which I think, I cannot able to do in gatsby-config (Please correct me if I am wrong). Please suggest me if I can pass 2 gtm tags to plugin on some condition or any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue too. I found the solution with the react-helmet. Here are the steps:

1. npm install gatsby-plugin-react-helmet react-helmet
2. Add plugin to gatsby-config.js -> plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`]
3. In the Seo.js file add your head TAG as below:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet"

const Seo = () => {

  return (
    <Helmet 
    title="Your title"
    description="Your description"
    meta={[
        {name:'google-site-verification', content:'copy your code from the Google Meta Tag'}
    ]}>  
    </Helmet>
  )
}

export default Seo
```