# How to trigger a Google Tag manager Trigger from my react (Gatsby) component?

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, gatsby

My Setup: I have added the Gatsby Google Tag manager plugin to my Gatsby code and have a couple of tags setup in my GTM dashbaod.

My Asks: 
How to trigger a tag when I dispatch an action to my redux saga?
Basically can someone show me how to trigger an a tag from my code? The Gatsby documentation has no mention of this for their plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use the Google Tag Manager plugin for gatsby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52883774/how-to-use-the-google-tag-manager-plugin-for-gatsby)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use redux saga one solution to consider using [redux beacon](https://github.com/rangle/redux-beacon) to solve this. The documentation is pretty straightforward. You map your actions to a GTM function. I've found this to be very approachable for doing these tasks.

in pseudo code off the top of my head its something like...

```
const myDataLayerPushFunction = (stateIn, stateOut, action) => {
  return {
    event: stateIn.event.i.am.mapping
  }
}

export eventsMap = [
  actionYouWantToTarget: mydataLayerPushFunction
]
```